# How can I generate incremental Maven build in Jenkins Job DSL?

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to generate what appears in my Jenkins Maven job under `Advanced...` as

```
Incremental build - only build changed modules
```

This is an XML node that's directly within `<maven2-moduleset>`.

I didn't find it in the API, so I thought I'd use `configure`, but I can't figure it out. From what I understand, this should work:

```
mavenJob('foo') {
  rootPOM('foo/pom.xml')
  goals('clean package')
  configure { node ->
    node {
      incrementalBuild('true')
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get an Exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.Node.call() is applicable for argument types: (Generator$_run_closure1_closure14_closure16) values: [Generator$_run_closure1_closure14_closure16@1f7d8eff]
Possible solutions: wait(), name(), value(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you must use the `/` operator in the configure block to create or update an element, see [Transforming XML](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block#transforming-xml) in the Job DSL wiki.

```
mavenJob('foo') {
  rootPOM('foo/pom.xml')
  goals('clean package')
  configure { node ->
    node / incrementalBuild(true)
  }
}
```